# Symfony and Doctrine: OneToOne Relation as Primary Key for an entity

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I've been wasting quite some time in this. I have two tables and two relations:

```
Person
Documents

One person has one document, and I want it to be the persons primary key.
Many documents can be associated with one person.
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Now, doctrine does`t seem to let my use a relation as a primary key:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Dni")
 */
private $dni;
```

Keep getting back this error:

```
Column name `dni` referenced for relation "Some entity which references a Person" towards Person does not exist.
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: What you describe actually sounds like a Many-to-one relation: *One* person per DNI, but *many* DNI per person.

Comment: OneToOne on the Person side, ManyToOne on the Dni side.

Comment: Your description and graph say completely opposite things. In text you wrote about one document to one person, but on graph you state you want many-to-one. Please, correct your question.

Comment: I corrected the description, sorry.